# Devices USB grounding

Tags: ground, grounding, usb-device, ground-loop, pc

I just opened a PC a client brought, with some software problems.

While fixing those problems I opened the case to check if there was something that needed maintenance and I noticed the USB shield of the front panel wasn't connected to the motherboard's ground or the mains ground, and it got me thinking because I thought it was always connected.

I did some research and found several proposals:

- Directly connect it to the chassis
- Connect it to the chassis through a RC filter (0.47 µF capacitor / 1 Mohm resistor) (The only excuse I saw for using this was "to prevent ESD".)
- Connect it to the chassis through a Fe bead
- Both options above (RC filter + Fe bead in series)
- Don't connect it at all

I don't see why any of the options besides the first I named would be good for a simple PC. Maybe someone could explain the reason for them?

NOTE: Even though I gave a particular example, I'd like a more general answer. I believe these concepts could be applied in a wider range.

Comment: Whatever makes you pass radiated emissions is good. All choices which result in failing radiated emissions are bad. For devices (as opposed to PC hosts) there may not be a chassis, per se.

Comment: Was it connected to the USB socket ground pin? Ugly but saves the cost of a separate shield connection so I wouldn't put it past a PC maker to do that.